# Type inference issue while building a LinkedList in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create a LinkedList Data Structure from scratch in Kotlin. While constructing Node object it does not let me assign head to next parameter and gives the following error :

> Error:Error:line (21)Kotlin: Type inference failed: Cannot infer type
>   parameter T in constructor Node(value: T#1 (type parameter of
>   Node), next: Node? = ...) None of the following substitutions
>   (T#2 (type parameter of LinkedList),Node?) (Int,Node?) can
>   be applied to (Int,Node?)

**Node.kt**

```
data class Node<T>(var value: T, var next: Node<T>? = null) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return if (next != null) {

            "$value -> ${next.toString()}"

        } else {

            "$value"

        }

    }
}
```

**LinkedList.kt**

```
class LinkedList<T> {

    private var head: Node<T>? = null
    private var tail: Node<T>? = null
    private var size = 0

    fun isEmpty(): Boolean {
        return size == 0
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return "Empty List"

        } else {
            return head.toString()
        }
    }

    fun push(value: T) {
        head = Node(value = 5, next = head)
        if (tail == null) {
            tail = head
        }
        size++
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `LinkedList::push(value: T)` method, you do:

```
head = Node(value = 5, next = head)
```

I'm not sure where that `value = 5` comes from (maybe you were debugging), but it should probably be:

```
head = Node(value = value, next = head)
```

Comment: Happens with all of us :) I agree that the error you get is not understandable at all.